# How to play external audio files in android?

Tags: android

I am new in android development.
I tried to play external audio files on android.
But this notification was appeared. "The Player doesn't support this type of audio file".
I can't understand the reason.

this is my code.

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.a">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MusicActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.administrator.a.MusicActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MusicActivity.java

```
public class MusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

       /* MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aa);
        player.start();*/

        File audioPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "musics");
        File audio = new File(audioPath, "1.mp3");
        if (!audio.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", audio);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/mp3");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <external-path name="imageFiles" path="images/"/>
    <external-path name="pdfFiles" path="pdfs/"/>
    <external-path name="musicFiles" path="musics/"/>
</paths>
```

the file "1.mp3" already exists in musics subdiretory of sdcard.
this is my result of running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMTQF.png)

please help me.

Comment: hello. Bheda, thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the way. but regretfully the issue was not fixed yet.

Comment: How can i do now?

Answer (score 1):

if you have to read and write any content from external storage then add this permission in your manifest file above the application tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.a">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MusicActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.administrator.a.MusicActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Glad it worked.Please accept my answer.You can also visit : https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.